# Cannot compile wxWidgets Hello World

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

So, I was trying to compile hello world example provided by wxWidgets but was unsuccessful in doing so. I will explain what I have done step by step to the current point where I am stuck.

#### Compiling wxWidgets

1. First of all, my compiler of choice is MinGw-w64, and since wxWidgets advise to build their library from source (downloaded from [wxWidgets download](https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/)),  I decided to do so using CMake.
2. I created a directory called **`cmake`** inside the root directory of wxWidgets (in my case: `C:\C++\wxWidgets-3.1.3`). Also I created **`bin`** directory for storing the compiled binaries.
3. I then navigated to the **`cmake`** directory and run the following CMake configuration command:

   ```
   $ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. -D "wxBUILD_SHARED=OFF" -D "wxBUILD_MONOLITHIC=OFF" -D "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug" -D "CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc.exe" -D "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++.exe"
   ```

   then I started the build by using the following command:

   ```
   $ cmake --build . --target all
   ```

   The resulting **`.a`** files (*static library files*) were placed in the **`bin`** directory.
4. I repeated the step 3 with the `-D "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release"` parameter.
5. The generated `lib\gcc_x64_lib\mswu` and `lib\gcc_x64_lib\mswud` directories into the **`include`** directory for the convenience (as they contain **`setup.h`** header file).

As the result my **`C:\C++\wxWidgets-3.1.3\bin`** directory contains following files:

```
libwxexpat.a   libwxpngd.a        libwxtiff.a   wxbase31u_net.a   wxmsw31u_adv.a   wxmsw31u_media.a     wxmsw31u_stc.a      wxmsw31ud_core.a      wxmsw31ud_qa.a        wxmsw31ud_xrc.a
libwxexpatd.a  libwxregexu.a      libwxtiffd.a  wxbase31u_xml.a   wxmsw31u_aui.a   wxmsw31u_propgrid.a  wxmsw31u_webview.a  wxmsw31ud_gl.a        wxmsw31ud_ribbon.a    wxrc.exe*
libwxjpeg.a    libwxregexud.a     libwxzlib.a   wxbase31ud.a      wxmsw31u_core.a  wxmsw31u_qa.a        wxmsw31u_xrc.a      wxmsw31ud_html.a      wxmsw31ud_richtext.a
libwxjpegd.a   libwxscintilla.a   libwxzlibd.a  wxbase31ud_net.a  wxmsw31u_gl.a    wxmsw31u_ribbon.a    wxmsw31ud_adv.a     wxmsw31ud_media.a     wxmsw31ud_stc.a
libwxpng.a     libwxscintillad.a  wxbase31u.a   wxbase31ud_xml.a  wxmsw31u_html.a  wxmsw31u_richtext.a  wxmsw31ud_aui.a     wxmsw31ud_propgrid.a  wxmsw31ud_webview.a
```

#### Creating Hello World project

I created simple wxWidgets hello world project with the following file structure:

```
app
|   build
|   headers
|   sources
|   |    main.cpp
|   CMakeLists.txt
```

The contents of **`main.cpp`**:

```cpp
// wxWidgets "Hello World" Program
// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include <wx/wxprec.h>

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MyFrame();

private:
    void OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
};

enum {
    ID_Hello = 1
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame();
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(): wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "Hello World") {
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_Hello, "&Hello...\tCtrl-H", "Help string shown in status bar for this menu item");
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append(wxID_EXIT);

    wxMenu *menuHelp = new wxMenu;
    menuHelp->Append(wxID_ABOUT);

    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");

    SetMenuBar( menuBar );
    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");

    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnHello, this, ID_Hello);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this, wxID_ABOUT);
    Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &MyFrame::OnExit, this, wxID_EXIT);
}

void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    wxMessageBox("This is a wxWidgets Hello World example", "About Hello World", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
}

void MyFrame::OnHello(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    wxLogMessage("Hello world from wxWidgets!");
}
```

The contents of **`CMakeLists.txt`**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(hello_world)

if (MINGW)
    add_compile_options(--static)
endif()

set(wx_libraries_path "C:\\C++\\wxWidgets-3.1.3\\bin")

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    include_directories("C:\\C++\\wxWidgets-3.1.3\\include\\mswud")
    find_library(libwxexpat       NAMES libwxexpatd        PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxjpeg        NAMES libwxjpegd         PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxpng         NAMES libwxpngd          PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxregexu      NAMES libwxregexud       PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxscintilla   NAMES libwxscintillad    PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxtiff        NAMES libwxtiffd         PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxzlib        NAMES libwxzlibd         PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxbase31u        NAMES wxbase31ud         PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxbase31u_xml    NAMES wxbase31ud_net     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxbase31u_net    NAMES wxbase31ud_xml     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_adv     NAMES wxmsw31ud_adv      PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_aui     NAMES wxmsw31ud_aui      PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_core    NAMES wxmsw31ud_core     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_gl      NAMES wxmsw31ud_gl       PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_html    NAMES wxmsw31ud_html     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_media   NAMES wxmsw31ud_media    PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_propgri NAMES wxmsw31ud_propgrid PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_qa      NAMES wxmsw31ud_qa       PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_ribbon  NAMES wxmsw31ud_ribbon   PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_richtex NAMES wxmsw31ud_richtext PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_stc     NAMES wxmsw31ud_stc      PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_webview NAMES wxmsw31ud_webview  PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_xrc     NAMES wxmsw31ud_xrc      PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
endif()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    include_directories("C:\\C++\\wxWidgets-3.1.3\\include\\mswu")
    find_library(libwxexpat       NAMES libwxexpat       PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxjpeg        NAMES libwxjpeg        PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxpng         NAMES libwxpng         PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxregexu      NAMES libwxregexu      PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxscintilla   NAMES libwxscintilla   PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxtiff        NAMES libwxtiff        PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(libwxzlib        NAMES libwxzlib        PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxbase31u        NAMES wxbase31u        PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxbase31u_xml    NAMES wxbase31u_xml    PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxbase31u_net    NAMES wxbase31u_net    PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_adv     NAMES wxmsw31u_adv     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_aui     NAMES wxmsw31u_aui     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_core    NAMES wxmsw31u_core    PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_gl      NAMES wxmsw31u_gl      PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_html    NAMES wxmsw31u_html    PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_media   NAMES wxmsw31u_media   PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_propgri NAMES wxmsw31u_propgri PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_qa      NAMES wxmsw31u_qa      PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_ribbon  NAMES wxmsw31u_ribbon  PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_richtex NAMES wxmsw31u_richtex PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_stc     NAMES wxmsw31u_stc     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_webview NAMES wxmsw31u_webview PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
    find_library(wxmsw31u_xrc     NAMES wxmsw31u_xrc     PATH ${wx_libraries_path})
endif()

include_directories("C:\\C++\\wxWidgets-3.1.3\\include")
link_directories("C:\\C++\\wxWidgets-3.1.3\\bin")

add_executable(app sources/main.cpp)

message(STATUS "${libwxexpat}")
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE
    ${libwxexpat}
    ${libwxjpeg}
    ${libwxpng}
    ${libwxregexu}
    ${libwxscintilla}
    ${libwxtiff}
    ${libwxzlib}
    ${wxbase31u}
    ${wxbase31u_xml}
    ${wxbase31u_net}
    ${wxmsw31u_adv}
    ${wxmsw31u_aui}
    ${wxmsw31u_core}
    ${wxmsw31u_gl}
    ${wxmsw31u_html}
    ${wxmsw31u_media}
    ${wxmsw31u_propgrid}
    ${wxmsw31u_qa}
    ${wxmsw31u_ribbon}
    ${wxmsw31u_richtext}
    ${wxmsw31u_stc}
    ${wxmsw31u_webview}
    ${wxmsw31u_xrc}
)
```

After I created project files I executed following CMake command to configure the project:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. -D "CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc.exe" -D "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++.exe" -D "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" -D "CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON"
```

Then I tried and failed to build the project with the following CMake command:

```
cmake --build .
```

#### Compilation errors

Unfortunately, the program fails to compile with, here is the output:

````
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer\build\CMakeFiles C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer\build\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/C++/MingGW-w64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build'
C:/C++/MingGW-w64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\app.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/app.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer\build C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer\build C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer\build\CMakeFiles\app.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer\build\CMakeFiles\app.dir\DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build/CMakeFiles/app.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build/CMakeFiles/app.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target app
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build'
C:/C++/MingGW-w64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\app.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/app.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/app.dir/sources/main.cpp.obj
C:\C++\MingGW-w64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe   @CMakeFiles/app.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -g   --static -o CMakeFiles\app.dir\sources\main.cpp.obj -c C:\Users\Oiltanker\Git\Pepega-Inject\installer\sources\main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable app.exe
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\app.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a
C:\C++\MingGW-w64\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\app.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\C++\MingGW-w64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\app.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o app.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libapp.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\app.dir\linklibs.rsp
C:/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.3/bin/wxbase31ud.a(dlmsw.cpp.obj): In function `GetFileVersion':
C:/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.3/src/msw/dlmsw.cpp:67: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoSizeW'
      .......
C:/C++/wxWidgets-3.1.3/src/common/geometry.cpp:350: undefined reference to `wxDataInputStream::Read32()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\app.dir\build.make:110: app.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Oiltanker/Git/Pepega-Inject/installer/build'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:86: all] Error 2```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. After I started searching on internet for answers and I found wxWidgets project CMakeLists.txt example that didn't work because it needed some variables set. After I set them correctly, I managed to compile hello world example.

Here is the contents of CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(hello_world)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

aux_source_directory(src SRC_LIST)

set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "C:/C++/wxWidgets")
set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "C:/C++/wxWidgets/lib/gcc_x64_lib")
set(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES "C:/C++/wxWidgets/lib")
set(wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/C++/wxWidgets/include/wx")

set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswud)
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

#### Process in detail

I deleted wxWidgets and recompiled them.

1. This time the wxWidgets source code was located in `C:\C++\wxWidgets-source` directory
2. I built `install` target to the `C:\C++\wxWidgets` directory with the following command:

   ```
   $ cmake --build . --target install
   ```

   You can specify the destination where your installation will go to by altering `wxINSTALL_PREFIX` definition in **`setup.h`** file and alerting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` definition in **`cmake_install.cmake`** file.

   - In case of **debug** configuration, the **`setup.h`** file will be located in `<cmake_building_directory>\lib\gcc_x64_lib\mswud\wx`
   - In case of **release** configuration, the **`setup.h`** file will be located in `<cmake_building_directory>\lib\gcc_x64_lib\mswu\wx`

I was also told that wxWidgets might have a specific linking order and that `find_package` function solves automatically, whether it is true or not I cannot tell.

Comment: if you are working with minggw or gcc the inking order does matter. MSVC does not care. And of course you coud've aso compile wxWidgets without using CMake and the just build `minimal` sample, which is in essence almost the same as you `Hello Word` - the difference is `minimal` sample is official and `Hello world` is not.

Comment: @Igor can you tell me then what is the difference between ``find_library`` and ``find_package`` ?

Comment: no idea. Never used the `CMake` thing. Using MSVC and official build instruction alone with provided `Makefile`s. Remember wxWidgets provides everything for you to do the build and start working with the library. `No need to reinvent the wheel and do it again.` And of course the official build documentation explains everything.

Comment: @Igor this is exactly why they provide ``CMakeLists.txt`` so you can build using CMake without "reinventing the wheel". And official documentation is vague in some crucial parts, that is why I was having trouble in the first place.

Comment: please re-read my answer. it is as simple as type `cd c:\wxWidgets\build\msw && mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc` and hit <Enter>. Then the library will be built based on the already provided `Makefile`. You don't need to play with CMake, Bakefile or anything else for that matter. Now using `CMake` is reinventing the wheel, because the makefile is already there, and the minimal sample is also already there. You actually spend more time writing `CMake` build rule than typing the easy command I gave in this message.

Comment: And on top of that there is a minimal sample which is exactly the code you were using for you so called `Hello World`. Except that the sample already contain everything you need to build and run it. Now it would be amazing if `CMake`, `Bakefile` or any other Makefile-generated thing wold not be available for users of the library and they would be kept private `for maintainers only`. Then there will be one way and only way to build. Oh well...

Comment: Now, it would be very interesting to know what official documentation didn't explain in the first place to make you switch to `CMake` crap. And I say `crap` because for me its extra tool that is completely unnecessary. Because if we can improve the documentation on how to build wxWidgets with MinGW on Windows it would be a huge improvement.

Comment: If you don't want any unnecessary tools why even have a make file then. Have you ever heard of such thing as convenience.

Comment: my point is - Makefile is already provided. And so using CMake is unneccessary at least to build the library. IMHO, CMake/bakefille should be used by core devs to generate Makefile or when you want to add a new file to the library. Then you need to regenerate the Makefile in order to test the build and submit a patch/PR. But if you just need to compile the library itself - everything is provided and you just wasted time by regenerating the Makefile itself.

Comment: Also as I write before `Now, it would be very interesting to know what official documentation didn't explain`.

Answer (score 1):

`GetFileVersionInfoSizeW()` lives in `version.dll`, so you need to link with `version.lib` to get it.

`wxDataInputStream::Read32()` is more surprising, it really should be present in `wxbase` library that you're linking with. Try checking if it's really there using `nm` or `objdump`.

Comment: Can you explain where I can get that version.dll library file, because the compilation of wxWidgets did not produce the file you mentioned?

Comment: `version.lib` is called `libversion.a` with MinGW and is provided in the distribution (under `i686-w64-mingw32/lib` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` directory, depending on whether you use 32- or 64-bit version, but this doesn't really matter, you just need to link with `-lversion`).

Answer (score 0):

On top what Vadim said - all you play with CMake and friends to compile wxWidgets are unnecessary.

wxWidgets already provide Makefile to compile the library. The are stored in wxWidgets\build\msw.

So all you could've done is:

```
cd C:\C++\wxWidgets-3.1.3\buid\msw
mingw64-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD="debug"
```

Then since wxWidgets already provides the minimal sample for the people to try all you woud be doing is:

```
cd C:\C++\wxWidgets\samples\minimal
mingw64-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD="debug"
./minimal.exe
```

This is much simper and would save you a lot of time.

On top of that - just a little suggestion - it looks like you are linking with a lot of libraries that you don't really need. For the minimal sample like this all you really need is wxbase and wxcore. All other are unnecessary.

Thank you.

Comment: I agree that I am linking needless libraries, but the list of undefined references is really really long, I was just trying to do everything in CMake just because I want to learn it.